# SQL Error ORA-00933

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I am executing a statement like this

```
       ResultSet res =
            stmt.executeQuery("SELECT FIRST_NAME FROM  USER vu, USER_PROFILE vup"+
                              "WHERE vup.USER_ID = vu.USER_ID  "+
                              "AND vu.USER_ID = ( SELECT USER_ID  "+
                             " FROM USER"+ 
                             " WHERE EMAIL_ID = '"+userName+"'"+ 
                             "AND PW_ENCRYPTED = '"+password+"')");
```

But it is returning an error like this

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: ORA-00933 is a syntax error.  It almost always points to a typo or similar mistake in our SQL.  A careful scan of the command should be enough to spot the bloomer.  When using dynamic SQL it helps to dump out the assembled statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add space at the start and end of the query lines. Like below

```
ResultSet res =
            stmt.executeQuery(" SELECT FIRST_NAME FROM  USER vu, USER_PROFILE vup "+
                              " WHERE vup.USER_ID = vu.USER_ID "+
                              "AND vu.USER_ID = ( SELECT USER_ID "+
                             " FROM USER "+ 
                             " WHERE EMAIL_ID = '"+userName+"' "+ 
                             " AND PW_ENCRYPTED = '"+password+"')");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a a space between `vup` and `WHERE`:

```
" WHERE vup.USER_ID = vu.USER_ID  " +
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), secondly, you are missing a space character between `vup` and `WHERE`.

It should look like this:

```
String sql = "SELECT FIRST_NAME FROM  USER vu, USER_PROFILE vup"
        + " WHERE vup.USER_ID = vu.USER_ID AND vu.USER_ID = "
        + "(SELECT USER_ID FROM USER WHERE EMAIL_ID = ? AND PW_ENCRYPTED = ?)";

ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, userName);
ps.setString(2, password);

rs = ps.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()) { }
```